# Excel: If the above statement is true, then skip the next x number of lines (or go to that specific one)

Tags: vba, excel

**strong text**Good afternoon,

I have spent a few months on a pretty lengthy macro for a project at work and I am close to the end but I keep encountering errors, mostly because the macro has to run on reports with a lot of data gaps (grrrr).

So I have a list of IF conditions. And the macro runs them all on each cell of a column, before going to next row. My problem is that this creates an error (please see code below)

```
Dim degreeCol As Integer  
degreeCol = ws.Rows(1).Find("Degree").Column  
Dim gradDateCol As Integer  
gradDateCol = ws.Rows(1).Find("Graduation Date (MM/DD/YYYY)").Column
Dim bsGradDateCol As Integer
bsGradDateCol = ws.Rows(1).Find("B.S. Graduation Date").Column
For row = 2 To endRow
    If ws.Cells(row, gradDateCol).Value = "" Then
        ws.Cells(row, bsGradDateCol).Value = "No Data"
    End If
    If ws.Cells(row, degreeCol).Value = "" And ws.Cells(row, gradDateCol).Value <> "" Then 
        ws.Cells(row, bsGradDateCol).Value = ws.Cells(row, gradDateCol).Value
    End If
    If ws.Cells(row, degreeCol).Value = "Bachelor's degree (±16 years)" Then
        ws.Cells(row, bsGradDateCol).Value = ws.Cells(row, gradDateCol).Value
    End If
    If ws.Cells(row, degreeCol).Value = "Doctorate degree over (±19 years)" Then
        ws.Cells(row, bsGradDateCol).Value = DateAdd("yyyy", -3, ws.Cells(row, gradDateCol).Value)
    End If
    If ws.Cells(row, degreeCol).Value = "Master's degree (±18 years)" Then
        ws.Cells(row, bsGradDateCol).Value = DateAdd("yyyy", -2, ws.Cells(row, gradDateCol).Value)
    End If
    If ws.Cells(row, degreeCol).Value = "Non degree program (±14 years)" Then
        ws.Cells(row, bsGradDateCol).Value = DateAdd("yyyy", 2, ws.Cells(row, gradDateCol).Value)
    End If
    If ws.Cells(row, degreeCol).Value = "Associate's degree college diploma (±13 years)" Then
        ws.Cells(row, bsGradDateCol).Value = DateAdd("yyyy", 3, ws.Cells(row, gradDateCol).Value)
    End If
    If ws.Cells(row, degreeCol).Value = "Technical diploma (±12 years)" Then
        ws.Cells(row, bsGradDateCol).Value = DateAdd("yyyy", 4, ws.Cells(row, gradDateCol).Value)
    End If
    If ws.Cells(row, degreeCol).Value = "" And ws.Cells(row, gradDateCol).Value <> "" Then
        ws.Cells(row, bsGradDateCol).Value = ws.Cells(row, gradDateCol).Value
    End If
Next row
```

So I have three columns: Degree, Graduation Date and B.S. Graduation Date. I ask the macro to fill in the B.S. Graduation Date column by taking and changing the value from the Graduation Date column depending on what the Degree column says. And because I have no control on the report and it can change I go with column headers rather than coordinates.

Now, as I said my problem comes from the fact that for each row the macro checks every of these and some rows have data gaps. So for example one row has "Master's Degree" in the Degree column but no dates. The macro will apply the first line and fill in the B.S. Grad Date cell with "No Data" but then when it gets to the "Master's Degree" line it stops and gives me an error because obviously there is no date for it to substract two years to.

I thought about it and tried different statements (IF ELSE for example) but I still think the best way would be to find verbiage for the macro to consider that **if the above IF statement is true, then ignore the other statements and go to next row**. It seemed easy at first but so far I have been unable to include this solution in the macro.

Could anyone provide some help/advice/suggestions/criticism on that?

Thanks!

Comment: What error do you get? On what line?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but i need to say this: **wrong approach**! One of the best programming practices is to define custom method if some piece of code is used several times. Another one is: to work on data, but not on "Excel-cells".

I'd suggest to use [Dictionary object](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/187234) together with function:

```
'Requires reference to MS Scripting Runtime.dll
Function GetGraduationDate(ByVal sGradDate As String, ByVal sDescription As String) As Variant  'Date if possible
Dim dic As Dictionary

Set dic = New Dictionary
dic.Add "Bachelor's degree (±16 years)", 0
dic.Add "Doctorate degree over (±19 years)", -3
dic.Add "Master's degree (±18 years)", -2
dic.Add "Non degree program (±14 years)", 2
dic.Add "Associate's degree college diploma (±13 years)", 3
dic.Add "Technical diploma (±12 years)", 4

If Not IsDate(sGradDate) Or sDescription = "" Then
    GetGraduationDate = "No data"
Else
    GetGraduationDate = DateAdd("yyyy", dic(sDescription), CDate(sGradDate))
End If

End Function
```

Usage:

```
Sub DoWhatever()

    For ...
         ws.Cells(row, bsGradDateCol) = GetGraduationDate(ws.Cells(row, degreeCol), _ 
          wsh.Cells(row, gradDateCol))

    Next    

End Sub
```

Where is a trick?

If GradDate is a proper date and Description is not an empty string, function looks up into dictionary object and returns value corresponding to the description.

Got it?